# How can I make a HTTPS call using HttpService in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to make an https call using HttpService. My code is working perfect when the url is http, but when i can the url to https is gives me the following error :

[RPC Fault faultString="Security error accessing url" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error" faultDetail="Destination: DefaultHTTP"]

How should I make a Https call??

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: have you checked the data flow with a tcp dump tool?

Answer (score 3):

Is your SWF hosted on the same domain? If so, is it being served over HTTPS as well? If the answer is no to either of those questions, you'll need a crossdomain.xml file at the root of the server hosting the service you want to call. You might check out [this Adobe article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html#allow-access-from-secure) on the subject.

For example, this would allow a SWF served over HTTP on example.com to access HTTPS services on your server:

**crossdomain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
    "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="example.com" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Ensure that the crossdomain.xml file is accessible from the root of your domain (ie: http://myserver.com/crossdomain.xml).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the certificate is valid or accepted in the browser.

Tip: under windows it does not matter which browser you are using you have to accept the certificate in Internet Explorer.